# Dvorak Programmer Layout with OpenBSD

Tags: keyboard-layout, openbsd, dvorak

I've recently installed OpenBSD. When installing the OS I selected the normal Dvorak layout as the Dvorak Programmer wasn't present on the list.

After the install I wanted to change the layout with `kbd` I tried: `us.dvorak.programmer`, `us.dvorak_programmer`, `us.programmer` and many others but none of them worked.

I also tried `kbd -l` but the command won't display anything.

What other ways are there to change the layout? I know I could use `setxkbmap` but that would only chage the keymap for x.org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kbd -l` reads from `/dev/wskbd%d` (for all available integers `%d`, 0 to 3 on my OpenBSD 6.4 system).  These devices are readable only by root, so you would have to use

```
doas kbd -l
```

to get anything back as an ordinary user, provided you have configured [`doas`](https://man.openbsd.org/doas), or by using `kbd -l` as root by other means.

The Dvorak-related encodings I can see are

```
fr.dvorak
us.dvorak
fr.swapctrlcaps.dvorak
us.swapctrlcaps.dvorak
```

Personally, I use `us.dvorak`.  As far as I know, only the numbers row is different on the programmer's Dvorak layout.

Someone is [currently implementing Colemak](https://marc.info/?t=154237665500006&r=1&w=2).  You could look at their efforts and make changes to a copy of the existing `us.dvorak` layout (or however a variant layout should be implemented), and then contribute that.

See also:

- [`pckbd(4)`](https://man.openbsd.org/pckbd)
- [`ukbd(4)`](https://man.openbsd.org/ukbd)

---

The Colemak keyboard layout mentioned above in 2018 [is available](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&m=155758437011079&w=2) in the base system as `us.colemak` since OpenBSD 6.6.

Using `kbd -l` without being root used to fail silently.  This behaviour [is being changed](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&m=165021680931002&w=2) for OpenBSD 7.2.